# Which actors have worked with the greatest numbers of other actors in the set of films observed in the data?

Tags: mysql

Which actors have worked with the greatest numbers of other actors in the set of films observed in the data?

```
mysql> show columns from film_actor;
+-------------+----------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field       | Type                 | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-------------+----------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| actor_id    | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              |                             |
| film_id     | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              |                             |
| last_update | timestamp            | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+-------------+----------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> show columns from actor ;
+-------------+----------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field       | Type                 | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-------------+----------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| actor_id    | smallint(5) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| first_name  | varchar(45)          | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| last_name   | varchar(45)          | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| last_update | timestamp            | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+-------------+----------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.06 sec)

mysql> show columns from film ;
+----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field                | Type                                                                | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| film_id              | smallint(5) unsigned                                                | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| title                | varchar(255)                                                        | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| description          | text                                                                | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| release_year         | year(4)                                                             | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| language_id          | tinyint(3) unsigned                                                 | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| original_language_id | tinyint(3) unsigned                                                 | YES  | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| rental_duration      | tinyint(3) unsigned                                                 | NO   |     | 3                 |                             |
| rental_rate          | decimal(4,2)                                                        | NO   |     | 4.99              |                             |
| length               | smallint(5) unsigned                                                | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| replacement_cost     | decimal(5,2)                                                        | NO   |     | 19.99             |                             |
| rating               | enum('G','PG','PG-13','R','NC-17')                                  | YES  |     | G                 |                             |
| special_features     | set('Trailers','Commentaries','Deleted Scenes','Behind the Scenes') | YES  |     | NULL              |                             |
| last_update          | timestamp                                                           | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
13 rows in set (0.12 sec)
mysql> show columns from film_list ;
+-------------+------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field       | Type                               | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------------+------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| FID         | smallint(5) unsigned               | YES  |     | 0       |       |
| title       | varchar(255)                       | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| description | text                               | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| category    | varchar(25)                        | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| price       | decimal(4,2)                       | YES  |     | 4.99    |       |
| length      | smallint(5) unsigned               | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| rating      | enum('G','PG','PG-13','R','NC-17') | YES  |     | G       |       |
| actors      | text                               | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------------+------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
8 rows in set (0.57 sec)

mysql> select actors from film_list ;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| actors                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| PENELOPE GUINESS, CHRISTIAN GABLE, LUCILLE TRACY, SANDRA PECK, JOHNNY CAGE, MENA TEMPLE, WARREN NOLTE, OPRAH KILMER, ROCK DUKAKIS, MARY KEITEL                                                                           |
| BOB FAWCETT, MINNIE ZELLWEGER, SEAN GUINESS, CHRIS DEPP                                                                                                                                                                  |
| NICK WAHLBERG, BOB FAWCETT, CAMERON STREEP, RAY JOHANSSON, JULIANNE DENCH                                                                                                                                                |
| JODIE DEGENERES, SCARLETT DAMON, KENNETH PESCI, FAY WINSLET, OPRAH KILMER                                                                                                                                                |
| GARY PHOENIX, DUSTIN TAUTOU, MATTHEW LEIGH, MATTHEW CARREY, THORA TEMPLE                                                                                                                                                 |
| KIRSTEN PALTROW, SANDRA KILMER, JAYNE NEESON, WARREN NOLTE, MORGAN WILLIAMS, KENNETH HOFFMAN, REESE WEST                                                                                                                 |
```

Comment: Generate SQL Fidle for your data. it is hard to answer you from your question.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried because this looks like a trivial college homework assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a.*,COUNT(Distinct c.actor_id) as countOfAllOtherActorsInAllHisFilms
from actor a
left join film_actor b ON a.actor_id = b.actor_id
left join film_actor c ON ( b.film_id = c.film_id AND c.actor_id != a.actor_id)
WHERE 1
GROUP BY a.actor_id
ORDER BY countOfAllOtherActorsInAllHisFilms DESC
```

---

in case you'd like to filter out set of films:

```
select a.*,COUNT(Distinct c.actor_id) as countOfAllOtherActorsInAllHisFilms
from actor a
left join film_actor b ON a.actor_id = b.actor_id
left join film_actor c ON ( b.film_id = c.film_id AND c.actor_id != a.actor_id)
left join film d ON b.film_id=d.film_id
WHERE d.rating='G'
GROUP BY a.actor_id
ORDER BY countOfAllOtherActorsInAllHisFilms DESC
```

---

**edit:** I added keyword `distinct` to counting function. Without it, an actor will be counted two times if they appear in two films together.

Comment: Excellent! My only concern is, that several actors have COUNT > 200 - the total number of actors in the table actor...

Comment: **edit:** I added keyword distinct to counting function. Without it, an actor will be counted two times if they show in two films together.